# How to deserialize json?

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, serialization, token

My application using configurations to manage modpacks for a game, so the config loader works this way:

Here is the configurations.json:

```
{
"GameDirectory": "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\.mp-craft-project",
"Configurations": {
    "MP-Craft-Default": {
        "Name": "MP-Craft-Default",
        "JavaPath": "C:\\ProgramFiles\\Java\\jre-xxx\\bin\\javaw.exe",
        "FullScreenMode": "Enabled",
        "ModLoader": "MCF_1.0"
    },
    "New-Configuration": {
        "Name": "New-Configuration",
        "JavaPath": "C:\\ProgramFiles\\Java\\jre-xxx\\bin\\javaw.exe",
        "FullScreenMode": "Enabled",
        "ModLoader": "MCF_2.0"
    }
  }
}
```

And the strings in this json for example modloader, or fullscreenmode can be a same or different (unknown) variations.
I want to load all configuration by name, and load the settings of the selected configuration. Can someone help me, how can I deserialize this json.

I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json` to deserialize.

THX for help.

Comment: Which one are you trying to deserialize?  Allowing spaces in names might cause a problem: "Example Config" wont match "Example_Config"

Comment: are you getting these from somewhere else or are these your invention?  I ask because it seems it would be easier to combine them rather than trying to find B from text in A

Comment: So what I need to do: load the configurations, then load the selected configuration's settings.

Comment: Well, rather than saving the actual configs in a different json, by saving the name in A, save the actual configs...like this: http://pastebin.com/87WC5z2s  There are some problems with what you have - that string array contains 2 pieces of info - 0, 2, 4... are the "names" and 1, 3, 5 will be the file names - hard to manage.  ALSO if this is just your local storage and you arent sending them anywhere, XML serializer would be more appropriate

Comment: JSON is more for data exchange, if this is local storage, XML serialization would be better.  Either way, edit your question for the answer you want

Comment: I rolled back your edit - you cannot significantly change a question after an answer is posted.  If you have changed you mind on how you want to do it, you can post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 classes, one to contain the Config collection and various "global" data, and then a class for the items:

```
Public Class Configs
    Public Property GameDirectory As String

    Public Property Configurations As Dictionary(Of String, ConfigItem)

    Public Sub New()
        Configurations = New Dictionary(Of String, ConfigItem)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ConfigItem
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Property JavaPath As String
    Public Property FullScreenMode As String            ' I would use Boolean
    Public Property ModLoader As String
End Class
```

To create the collection class and store config items to it:

```
Imports System.Environment
...
Dim myCfgs As New Configs
myCfgs.GameDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), ".mp-craft-project")

Dim p As New ConfigItem
p.Name = "Ziggy"
p.FullScreenMode = "Enabled"
p.ModLoader = "MCF_1.0"
p.JavaPath = "C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jre-xxx\bin\javaw.exe"

' add this item to the collection
myCfgs.Configurations.Add(p.Name, p)

' add another, create a new ConfigItem object
p = New ConfigItem
p.Name = "Hoover"
p.FullScreenMode = "Enabled"
p.ModLoader = "MCF_2.0"
p.JavaPath = "...javaw.exe"
myCfgs.Configurations.Add(p.Name, p)
```

To get one out of the collection to work with:

```
Dim thisCfg As ConfigItem = myCfgs.Configurations("Ziggy")
Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, JavaPath: {1}, ModLoader: {2}",
                  thisCfg.Name, thisCfg.JavaPath, thisCfg.ModLoader)
```

The Output:

> Name: Ziggy, JavaPath: C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jre-xxx\bin\javaw.exe, ModLoader: MCF_1.0

To serialize/save it:

```
' save all configs to disk:
Dim jstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myCfgs)
File.WriteAllLines(saveFileName, jstr)
```

To load the last set of saved configs:

```
' load the text, then deserialize to a Configs object:
Dim jstr = File.ReadAllText(saveFileName)
Dim myCfgs As Configs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Configs)(jstr)
```

---

There are some refinements and cautions:

1. When storing path literals, dont use escape chars.  Use `"C:\path\file\..."` not `"C:\\path\\file\\..."`.  The serializer adds the extra `\`s
2. As noted, rather than parsing `Enabled` to determine full screen, I would use a Booleam.
3. I would avoid dashes, slashes and spaces and such in the names and keys
4. Some things might be better as Enums or Types, `"MCF_1.0"` for instance, so you do not have to parse it out to determine if it is `1`, `1.1` or `2.0`
5. Since the configs are in a Dictionary, you may want to read up on how to use them if you are not familiar with them.

Comment: You should post a new question so the code formats properly - I cant read that.  However, since it is not an array, you need to use `For Each`